# c# controlling datagridview columns drag and drop operation

Tags: c#, datagridview, drag-and-drop

I have a datagridview table and I want to disable drag and drop in some specific situations.

Example:

I have 4 columns named A,B,C,D. I divide them in to 2 groups: A,B  and C,D (for a user they look like 4 normal columns). Now when the user drags a column A or B, he can only drop it before C. When he drags C or D, he can only drop it after B.

I tried to detect the DisplayIndex values in the ColumnDisplayIndexChanged but this event is fired multiple times and I got an exeption that DisplayIndex is being changed or sth and I can't change it at that moment.

Is there any way to do sth like that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The drag-and-drop starts with the `DataGridView::MouseDown` event. There, you can remember which column was dragged

```
// Get the index of the item the mouse is below.
int columnIndexFromMouseDown = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).ColumnIndex;
// Get the name
string columnDragName = dataGridView1.Columns[columnIndexFromMouseDown].Name;
```

Remember the column name and check it against the 'drop to column' in `DataGridView::DragDrop`. If it can be dropped do your magic, otherwise do nothing if the column combination is incorrect.